# simple Minio bucket policy

Tags: minio

I am using a docker image of Minio in a Node development environment. The database seed creates a Minio bucket thusly:

```
await this.s3.createBucket({
  Bucket: this.configService.get('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
  ACL: 'public'
}).promise()
```

This creates the bucket nicely, but the ACL doesn't take at all. I can jump into the Minio browser at `http://localhost:9000` and manually set the bucket to public read, but that's obviously kind of cumbersome for a seed.

I've seen a lot of conflicting advice, suggesting things like "Minio doesn't even do ACLs, use a bucket policy," but I can't find a sample policy file anywhere, and the AWS JSON don't seem to work. I would really prefer not to do this via the CLI interface, as I don't want to have to build that into my deployments. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be that one cannot create the bucket and assign the policy in the same call. There needs to be two calls.

This wound up working:

```
    const S3_BUCKET = 'some_bucket_name'
    const policy = JSON.stringify({
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "*"
            ]
          },
          "Resource": [
            `arn:aws:s3:::${S3_BUCKET}/*`
          ],
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    })
    try {
      await this.s3.createBucket({ Bucket: S3_BUCKET }).promise()
      await this.s3.putBucketPolicy({ Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Policy: policy }).promise()
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.error(error, 'create:bucket')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An example can be found here:
[Set Bucket Policy in minio-js (node-js)](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/examples/set-bucket-policy.js)

```js
var Minio = require('minio')

var s3Client = new Minio.Client({
  endPoint: '<host>',
  accessKey: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
  secretKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY'
})
// Bucket policy - GET requests on "testbucket" bucket will not need authentication.
var policy = `
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket"
      ],
      "Sid": ""
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
      ],
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
`

s3Client.setBucketPolicy('testbucket', policy, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log('Set bucket policy')
})
```